# Kotlin Intent syntax error

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

Im trying to set `Intent` in Kotlin in Android Studio to launch another `Activity.kt`:

```
val i : Intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
```

Android Studio shows me an error, and it doesnt compile:

```
Error:(23, 26) None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public constructor Intent(p0: Context!, p1: Class<*>!) defined in android.content.Intent 
public constructor Intent(p0: String!, p1: Uri!) defined in android.content.Intent
```

I think syntax is correct, so what is wrong?

Comment: is 'this` of type `Context`?

Comment: Where is this particular line of code written ? In witch class ? In a method ? It's a top-level declaration ? Please copy maybe not the whole class but the relevant parts.

Comment: I have found error -  this@MainActivity is correct

Comment: val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, Activity::class.java)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, Activity::class.java)

Comment: thx @kamilp +1 for the working sol. but can you please give some explanation for **why we need to append `.java` at the end of the statement**.

Comment: @ Ravi Vaniya from what I see .java is a kotlin method from file JvmClassMapping.kt.
/**
 * Returns a Java [Class] instance corresponding to the given [KClass] instance.
 */
'@Suppress("UPPER_BOUND_VIOLATED")
public val <T> KClass<T>.java: Class<T>
    @JvmName("getJavaClass")
    get() = (this as ClassBasedDeclarationContainer).jClass as Class<T>'

So, probably Intent needs a java class, not kotlin class.

Comment: Ok ok, got it. Thx @kamilp

Answer (score 2):

You should use package context as follows:

```
val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity,MainActivity::class.java)
           startActivity(intent)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You should write like this:
`val i : Intent  by lazy { Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java) }`

Comment: Which will give exactly the same compilation error as the one in the original question. Your answer doesn't really help.

Comment: Yes, if `this` is not instance of `Context`