# How can I handle the cancel and the ok button in the dialog

Tags: kotlin, android-dialog

I want when I click the ok button is the dialog it does something,same as the cancel button

override
    fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

```
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this.requireActivity())

    // Dialog will have "Make a selection" as the title
    builder.setMessage("Details successfully captured.Do you wish to proceed and book your seat?")
        // An OK button that does nothing
        .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, id ->
            // Nothing happening here

        }
        // A "Cancel" button that does nothing
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, id ->
            // Nothing happening here either
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage("Yes or No")
            .setPositiveButton("OK"){ dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int ->
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Ok Pressed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    dialogInterface.dismiss()
            }
            .setNegativeButton("No"){ dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int ->
                    Toast.makeText(this,"No Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    dialogInterface.dismiss()
            }
```

The DialogInterface.OnClickListener has two params:-

dialog -> Dialog which receives the click
i -> the position of the item clicked

Write your execution logic like the toast above and you can use the dialog available to dismiss in the end.

Comment: You don't have to call `dismiss`. It will automatically dismiss the dialog when any of the buttons is pressed.

Comment: well, is it possible to make the ok button function and route me to another activity

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks for pointing out. My intention was to tell we can call the Dialog Interface methods using that.

Comment: @Saliko yes it is possible. You just need to put the logic for starting the activity there instead of Toast. Please check the link:- https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity

Comment: @Sandeep Kumar thanks for the tutorial.This is what I did afterwards but i get an error in the Intent object   .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, i: Int ->
                val intent = Intent(PickSeatActivity::class.java)
                //val  intent = Intent(this,PickSeatActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)

                

            }

Comment: @Sandeep Kumar, android studio underlines ....'Intent' object         and i get this when I point the cursor on the 'Intent' object     None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
<init>(Intent!) defined in android.content.Intent
<init>(String!) defined in android.content.Intent

Comment: @Saliko hard to guess from this android studio warning need more info about the situation.
Anyways can you please check if the situation is similar to the following:-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49173837/kotlin-intent-syntax-error

Answer (score 0):

I replaced my code to this and it worked out

```
    val intent = Intent(this.requireActivity(), PickSeatActivity::class.java)
         startActivity(intent)
```